# kustomize: namespace in common name of cert-manager certificate (variable inside string)

Tags: kubernetes, cert-manager, kustomize

I want to create a cert-manager certificate using kustomize, where the string of the commonName-Field contains the namespace. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such option to achieve it with Kustomize right out of the box.

Thankfully [Kustomize](https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/kustomize/guides/plugins/) offers a plugin framework, that allows you to write your own "transformation" plugin.

You could create it based on existing set of plugins from [Agilicus](https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/kustomize/guides/plugins/), released under Apache 2.0 license, specifically on the resemblance of the their [certificatetransformer](https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/kustomize/guides/plugins/) plugin, where you would need to modify it to match your needs.

So instead of letting it to replace namespace in `Certificate` resource, you would need to play around it with modifications on `['spec']['commonName']` list.